# Reliable alternative to waitfor() in Perl

Tags: perl

Here is the snippet of my script which will wait for string "username: " and print the username to login, huge chunk of boot-up message gets printed before "username: " appears, sometimes the script is missing to find the it and returning saying "Failed to find username:", especially when some spilled over boot-up messages get printed after "username: " prompt line, so is there a more reliable way to do this? Thanks.

```
my %words = (
   username => 'user1',
   username_string => 'username: $',
);
( $prematch, $match ) = $obj->{comm}->waitfor(Match => "/$words{username_string}/",Errmode => "return");
if ( !defined $match ) {
    print "Failed to find username:";
    return;
}
else {
  $obj->{comm}->print( $words{username} );
}
```

$obj is an object of Net::Telnet

Comment: waitfor() is obviously a method for some Class.  Helping you would be easier if we knew which Class that was...

Comment: Looks like it comes from [`Net::Telnet`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Telnet)

Comment: yes, sorry, it comes from NET::Telnet, I am still understanding the script which I am updating.

Answer (score 0):

in fact i do not know which kind of object is related to your $obj. assuming it could be Net::Telnet maybe this could help you:

[perl-telnet-does-not-wait-for-the-end-of-the-previous-command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199436/perl-telnet-does-not-wait-for-the-end-of-the-previous-command)

Futhermore:

```
( $prematch, $match ) = $obj->{comm}->waitfor(Match => "/$words{username_string}/",Errmode => "return");
```

maybe it is a better approach to capture the cmd output into an array variable

```
my @lines = $telnet->cmd($comm);
for (my $line: @lines) {
    # your matching goes here..
}
```

or try this:

```
$t = new Net::Telnet(Host =>"192.168.0.1", Timeout => 5,Port => "1701", Prompt => '/>\$ $/');
$t->print($comm);
$t->waitfor('/username: $/i');
print "result=", $s;
```